# SysML FlowProperties and FlowSpecification in Enterprise Architect (9.3)

Tags: model, enterprise-architect, sysml

I'm trying to define a SysML FlowSpecification and add FlowProperties to it. I can't find any specific way to add flow properties and the standard add Property dialog doesn't offer flow property specific attributes, such as "direction".
I tried to add flowProperties as standard properties using a handcrafted flowProperty sterotype and using a direction=in constraint, but EA doesn't show the direction constraint in the respective Block compartment.

In MagicDraw all of this works seamless, so I suspect I'm correct with the SysML approach as such.

Any help of how to properly model FlowSpecifications in EA is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

In Enterprise Architect if you add a flow port to any block, then the flow port will provide you with the appropriate/required properties.

It also shows the 'flow ports' compartment including the direction.

Comment: Ok so on further investigation it seems I was slightly off the mark. If you make a FlowSpecification composite (right click the element --> Advanced --> Make Composite), the toolbox for the resulting diagram will offer Flow Parts, this seems to be the FlowPropery. When used they create the appropriate compartment in the owing FlowSpecification.

Comment: you might want to completly remove your answer. It doesn't work.